# pass the password as an argument in pssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, pssh

I am trying to write a script which will run commands on multiple machines with `pssh`.
Is there any way to pass the password also in the same command line like below:

```
$ pssh -h pssh-host.txt -l root -A "pswd" echo "hi"
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
```

Tried following solution:

```
sshpass -pabc pssh -h pssh-host.txt -l root -A echo "hi"
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
[1] 13:55:56 [SUCCESS] x
[2] 13:55:56 [SUCCESS] y
```

I do not want this `Password:` prompt. Can someone suggest a way for this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nicwolff/7c113328412765eaf83e

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286772/how-to-make-parallel-ssh-stop-prompting-for-password

Comment: Tried from both the links, none worked. Any other solution?

Comment: @Peter, you can paste the solution as answer and I will accept it, thanks much! It worked!

Comment: BTW, passing a password as a command-line argument exposes it to every other user on your system (including untrusted users such as `nobody`). It's possible to rewrite argv, but only after startup is complete, meaning that there's an unavoidable window of exposure even if a program *tries* to prevent same. Consider using an environment variable (if your OS -- like modern Linux -- protects them from being read by other users) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossposting [an answer by user568109 on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286777/3113) as Community Wiki:

---

> Found the solution on net not long after posting the question.
>
> The solution is:
>
> 1. Install and use sshpass
> 2. Use interactive mode to force the password which is just an empty string
> 3. Used command `cat local | sshpass -ppassword parallel-ssh -I -h new_hosts -l root -A 'cat >> remote'`
>
> Original solution at:
>   http://www.getreu.net/public/downloads/doc/Secure_Computer_Cluster_Administration_with_SSH/